# asking about the L2 norm on the command governor

Tags: matlab, optimization, simulink

Hi sry for the interruption, I did not understand the following optimization equation for the command governor,

[image]

I don't understand how to find the Q  on the equation and how the equation is used, hope can get some help and feedback from you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the paper you're reading or at least the reference to the full paper for us to understand your problem.

Luckily I find that paper on IEEE with DOI: 10.1109/ACC.2014.6859176

In this case, J is the cost function and Q is the state cost matrix, just like in Linear quadratic regulator.

[LQR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbb8t.png)

You have to choose the matrix Q, so just start using an identity matrix, then modify it to see what happens.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my doubt and sorry for forgetting to provide the reference to you. By the way are u familiar with the command governor?